# Angle $\alpha$ is divided into parts such that the ratio of tangents is $k$ and the difference of parts is $x$. Show $\sin x=(k-1)/(k+1)\sin\alpha$.

Tags: trigonometry

> Let angle $\alpha$ be divided into two parts such that the ratio of their tangents is $k$ and the difference between the parts is $x$. Then show that
>
> $$\sin x = \frac{k-1}{k+1}\sin \alpha$$

I know the result can be derived easily using Componendo and Dividendo but is there a more intuitive way for the same?

Comment: Huh?  The formula fails pretty remarkably when $k\approx 1$.

Comment: Ahh thanks for pointing out the lapsus calami..It is k+1 in the denominator

Comment: You can avoid componendo et dividendo by clearing the denominator $\frac{k-1}{k+1}=\frac{(t_1/t_2)-1}{(t_1/t_2)+1}=\frac{t_1-t_2}{t_1+t_2}$ (that is, how we prove c&d), but otherwise the same proof.

Comment: Does that mean I have take in consideration the RHS first?

Comment: Something like that, yes.